# Passing a list into a method as a parameter

Tags: vb.net, list, parameters

I have 2 functions, one is:

```
Public Sub PopulateValidKeystrokeList()
    ValidKeystrokeList.Add(Keys.A)
    ValidKeystrokeList.Add(Keys.B)
    ValidKeystrokeList.Add(Keys.C)
    ValidKeystrokeList.Add(Keys.D)
    ValidKeystrokeList.Add(Keys.E)
    ValidKeystrokeList.Add(Keys.F)
    ValidKeystrokeList.Add(Keys.G)
    ValidKeystrokeList.Add(Keys.H)
    ValidKeystrokeList.Add(Keys.I)
    ValidKeystrokeList.Add(Keys.J)
    'backPopulateDictionary()
End Sub
```

And the other is this:

```
Public Function backPopulateDictionary(ByRef validkeylist As List(Of String))
    For i As Integer = 0 To ValidKeystrokeList.Count - 1
        keystrokeDictionary.Add(ValidKeystrokeList.Item(i), i)
    Next
    Return keystrokeDictionary
End Function
```

I need to pass the whole list into `backPopulateDictionary()` but I'm not sure how to pass a whole list as a parameter, since everything I have tried so far just errors out and doesn't work.

Comment: **What** have you tried? Passing the list is completely straightforward, *if* the types match (they don’t seem to match in your case …).

Comment: You don't have a return value for your function. Where exactly do your errors occur?

Comment: When I go to pass the info like `backPopulateDictionary(ValidKeystrokeList.)` I don't know what to put after the `.` everything I've tried (all, item,copy) doesn't work.

Comment: How do you pass normal function arguments? Do the same here.

Comment: If ValidKeystrokeList is a List(of String) then you just do backPopulateDictionary(ValidKeystrokeList) without the '.' you're sending a reference to the whole list.

Comment: I tried that it says there is an error

Comment: Figured it out! I needed to ByRef it as a key rather than a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Public Function backPopulateDictionary(ByVal validkeylist As List(Of String))
    For i As Integer = 0 To validkeylist.Count - 1
        keystrokeDictionary.Add(validkeylist.Item(i), i)
    Next
    Return keystrokeDictionary
End Function
```

And call it with `backPopulateDictionary(ValidKeystrokeList)`

`validkeylist` is the parameter, so when you are adding to your `keystrokeDictionary`, you need to use the parameter name - not the name of the actual list.